# What different grammatical uses exist for 而 in classical chinese?

Tags: grammar

The question itself is already sufficient in description. Whose brilliant brain had the idea to coerce this nonsensical additional commentary text on us?

Answer (score 1):

1. [conj.] (*almost*=**while**) a conj. with slight sense of transition/suppose, can be translated into: and;furthermore;moreover;but also;into the bargain;if;in case;however.

<连>

从古沿用下来的连词,可连接词、短语和分句,表示多种关系 [and;furthermore;moreover;but also;into the bargain;if;in case;however]

- (1)
  **(listing)**
  表示并列关系

永州之野产异蛇,黑质而白章。—— 唐· 柳宗元《捕蛇者说》

Wilderness of Eishu(Yongzhou) produces peculiar snakes, whose skin black and texture white.

- (2)
  **(progressing)**
  表示递进关系

君子博学而日参省乎己。——《荀子·劝学》

Kunshi (Junzi) (a noble one) broadly studies and furthermore daily introspect into himself.

- (3)
  **(a slight casual relationship)**
  表示承接关系

余方心动欲还,而大声发于水上。——宋· 苏轼《石钟山记》

I was just hesitating to go home, when great sound generates from the waters.

- (4)
  **(slight transition)**
  表示转折关系

青,取之于蓝,而青于蓝。——《荀子·劝学》

Ao (qin) is taken from Ai (lan), yet bluer/darker than Ai(lan).

- (5)
  **(surmise)**
  表示假设关系

诸君而(如果)有意;瞻余马首可也。——清· 徐珂《清稗类钞·战事类》

You fellows if interested, up-look into my horse's head's orientation.

- (6)**(modification, similar to suffix *-ly* in English)**
  表示修饰关系,连接状语

吾恂恂而起。——唐· 柳宗元《捕蛇者说》

I uneasily got up.

2. [pron.] you,your; this

〈代〉

- (1) 你;你的 [you;your]

余知而无罪也。——《左传·昭公二十年》

I know you are innocent.

- (2) 这样,此 [this]

同是被逼迫,君而妾亦然。——《玉台新咏·古诗为焦仲卿妻作》

Same enforced, you being so and I also being.

3. [aux.]

〈助〉

- (1)
  **(modification, "as to the extent")**
  表示偏正关系,相当于“之”,“的” [of]

虞之与虢,相恃而势。——《淮南子·人间》

Go(yu, ancient country) treating Kaku(guo, ancient country), take reciprocal reliance as the situation.

- (2)
  **(comparison, though sometimes the same positioning can be case 1.6)**
  与“上”、“下”、“前”、“后”、“来”、“往”连用,相当于“以”

形而上者谓之道,形而下者谓之器。——《易·系辞上》

Up to entity is called Tao, down to entity called mechanism.

3. [mod.]

<语气>

- (1)
  **(negative question)**
  用于句中,表示反问,相当于“难道”,“岂” [how could;how is it possible]

为仁由己,而由人乎哉?——《论语·颜渊》

To practice kindness is out of oneself, how could it be out of others?

- (2)
  **(exclamation)**
  用于句末,相当于“耳”,“哪”

已而已而,今之从政者殆而。——《论语·微子》

Finished already, finished already, today's politicians are stupid as such!

Ref:[ZDIC](http://www.zdic.net/z/21/xs/800C.htm)